# looping over keys and values, process the key values and store them back another dictinory in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I want to multiply the all the values stored in a dictionary. Can you suggest me the good way of doing that.

```
dict = {'x': [645, 469,456,790,850], 
        'y': [599, 548], 
        'z': [653,  672,150,590],
        'w': [653, 672,150,590]}
list = []
for i, j in dict.iteritems():
    #loop over all key's and get the values out and multiply with 1000
    value_ofkey = float(j[0])
    list.append = value_ofkey *1000
    value_ofkey = float(j[1])
list.append = value_ofkey *1000
```

Comment: what are you expecting as result? You need to tell us what the code actally supposed to do?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want to do. Do you want to multiply each value in the dictionary by 1000? Could you post your expected output?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. want to multiply each value in the dictionary by 1000, and then add to new dictionary with out altering the key's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly do not name your variable as `dict` as it is a builtin.

Now to solve your problem you can try a [list-comprehesion](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) within a dict-comprehension.

```
>>> dic = {'x': [645, 469,456,790,850], 
...         'y': [599, 548], 
...         'z': [653,  672,150,590],
...         'w': [653, 672,150,590]}
>>> newdic = {key:[i*1000 for i in val] for key,val in dic.items()}
>>> newdic
{'y': [599000, 548000], 'x': [645000, 469000, 456000, 790000, 850000], 'z': [653000, 672000, 150000, 590000], 'w': [653000, 672000, 150000, 590000]}
```

**POST COMMENT EDIT**

You can restrict the required keys using `if` condition.

```
newdic = {key:[i*1000 if key != 'x' else i for i in val] for key,val in dic.items()}
```

For a number of such keys you can try

```
newdic = {key:[i*1000 if key not in ('x','y') else i for i in val] for key,val in dic.items()}
```

Working

```
>>> newdic = {key:[i*1000 if key != 'x' else i for i in val] for key,val in dic.items()}
>>> newdic
{'y': [599000, 548000], 'x': [645, 469, 456, 790, 850], 'z': [653000, 672000, 150000, 590000], 'w': [653000, 672000, 150000, 590000]}
>>> newdic = {key:[i*1000 if key not in ('x','y') else i for i in val] for key,val in dic.items()}
>>> newdic
{'y': [599, 548], 'x': [645, 469, 456, 790, 850], 'z': [653000, 672000, 150000, 590000], 'w': [653000, 672000, 150000, 590000]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information.  Your code works exactly for me.Can you also help me further more.  1. I dont want to multiply the specific key say "x" but I want to multiply(with 1000) all other key values (y,z)    2.  I am trying multiply the values with exp(3), because some of the dictionary values has exponential values(-1.1e3)

Comment: @TestEngineer Certainly (if it is within the rules of SO)

Comment: Thanks for the information.  Your code works exactly for me.Can you also help me further more.  1. I dont want to multiply the specific key say "x" but I want to multiply(with 1000) all other key values (y,z)    2.  I am trying multiply the values with exp(3), because some of the dictionary values has exponential values(-1.1e3)                                      newdic = {key:[i*exp(3) for i in val] for key,val in dic.items()}     this code is not giving the proper values which we got earlier

Comment: @TestEngineer I have updated my answer with your first doubt. With regards to 2. I am sorry to mention that it lies outside the scope of this question. [Ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with the code that you are using and how it is not working (Note that you need to add proper data which is not working) along with the complete traceback.

Comment: Can we have  if condition to check for exponential values and replace with '0' and if not 10**6

Comment: @TestEngineer I have added an answer in your other question as it is more appropriate there!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you want to extract all values, multiply them by 1000, and then add each new value to a results list.

This code multiplies by 1000 all items from the dictionary's values and adds them to `results`:

```
data = {'x': [645, 469,456,790,850], 
        'y': [599, 548], 
        'z': [653,  672,150,590],
        'w': [653, 672,150,590]}
results = []

for l in data.values():
    results.extend(i*1000 for i in l)

>>> print results
[599000, 548000, 645000, 469000, 456000, 790000, 850000, 653000, 672000, 150000, 590000, 653000, 672000, 150000, 590000]
```

Or you could, with a little help from `itertools.chain()` use a list comprehension to achieve the same in one line of code:

```
import itertools
results = [v*1000 for v in itertools.chain(*data.values())]
>>> print results
[599000, 548000, 645000, 469000, 456000, 790000, 850000, 653000, 672000, 150000, 590000, 653000, 672000, 150000, 590000]
```

Note that the order of values in the list in indeterminate due to the nature of dictionaries not having an inherent order.

If you want to update the dictionary in place:

```
for v in data.values():
    for i in range(len(values)):
        v[i] *= 1000
>>> print data
{'y': [599000, 548000], 'x': [645000, 469000, 456000, 790000, 850000], 'z': [653000, 672000, 150000, 590000], 'w': [653000, 672000, 150000, 590000]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am expecting dictionary. So your last piece code is look's work's for me

Comment: @TestEngineer: OK thanks for the accept and the feedback. I could have sworn that your code was attempting to append values to a list :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary comprehension with lambda. I changed `dict` to `dict1`.

```
dict1 = {'x': [645, 469,456,790,850], 
        'y': [599, 548], 
        'z': [653,  672,150,590],
        'w': [653, 672,150,590]}


dict2 = {k: map(lambda num: num*1000, v) for k,v in dict1.iteritems()}
print (dict2)
```

Output:

```
{'y': [599000, 548000], 'x': [645000, 469000, 456000, 790000, 850000], 'z': [653000, 672000, 150000, 590000], 'w': [653000, 672000, 150000, 590000]}
```

Comment: This works only for Python2. `map` returns mapobj in py3. (Yep I know OP has tagged py2.7 but still)

Comment: @BhargavRao Thanks for that! Yes, this solution is definitely for Python2

Comment: Good answer there. But to get extra benefits, 1. Mention why you *changed dict to dict1* 2. Explain `map` or else add a link to `map` documentation (python2 and not python3). 3. Add a small note stating that it works only for py2.

Comment: @BhargavRao Thanks very much for the helpful suggestions, I appreciate it. I agree, I should add explanation and links to my answers. Very good advise.